# Kotlin get value by key from map

Tags: java, kotlin

Let's assume we have a map:

```
val charToCount = mapOf('a', 3)
```

The task is to retrieve the value `3` by the corresponding key. The problem is `map.get(...)` returns nullable type `T?` instead of `T`. What's the best practice to convert the value to non-nullable type if there is a guarantee that the key is present in the map and the corresponding value `!= null`?

Off the top of my head there are two ways:

1. `val count = charToCount['a']!!`
2. `val count = charToCount['a'] ?: error("...")`

But both of them don't seem concise. Are there any better approaches to chip away with a nullable type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appropriate method is

```
val count: Int = charToCount.getValue('a')
```

...which "throws an exception if there is no such key in the map," according to its docs.

Sorry if you were hoping for something more concise; if you want something *short*, you can't possibly beat `!!`.