# Dealing with realtime firebase values once obtained

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

For my next app it requires a lot of cloud reading/writing to firebase. At the moment to get info on the users profile I use.

```
myRef.child(userid).child("UserName").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.i("firebase", "Got value ${it.value}")
            //what I need to do with the value
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
        }

myRef.child(userid).child("Bio").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.i("firebase", "Got value ${it.value}")
            //what I need to do with the value
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
        }
//so on for all my values
```

So I was wondering, because all the data is stored under the same path "userid" being the ID of the User, If I could get all the data from that section and then filture the hashmap of data it returns for each section. I tried this by -

```
        myRef.child(userid).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.i("firebase", "Got values ${it.value}")
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
        }
```

And this returns all the data in this format: `Got values {UserName=Joshu, Bio=I am joshu, the creator of this app, Gender=Male, Age=15}`

My question is, How can I segment this data so I can use it for textviews in my app?

I previously tried:

```
val userData = document.data?.values 
      ?.filterIsInstance<String>()
```

But this still returns a list of values (Like this - `[Joshu, I am joshu, the creator of this app, Male, 15]`) that I have found really difficult to use in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request the full node for a user, the `it` is a [`DataSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) and `it.value` will be a `Map<String, Object>` with all the properties under that node.

So you can either use `it.value` and [get the property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625231/kotlin-get-value-by-key-from-map) you want from that dictionary, or you can use the built-in [`child` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#child(java.lang.String)) of the snapshot to get the correct child and then call `value` on that.

Untested, but it should be something like this for the first approach:

```
myRef.child(userid).get().addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.i("firebase", "Got value: "+(it.value as Map<String, Object>).getValue("UserName"))
}.addOnFailureListener {
    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
}
```

Or this for the second approach

```
myRef.child(userid).get().addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.i("firebase", "Got value: "+it.child("UserName").value)
}.addOnFailureListener {
    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
}
```